# Coqide Key Bindings Bug(?)

Tags: keyboard, coq, proof, coqide

I'm having a bit of an odd problem... recently I've been having some odd situations arising whilst using CoqIDE, namely:

1. I can't type the letter "v" without holding down the windows/super key.
2. Pressing backspace moves the focus to the previous tab if multiple windows are open, I can't delete things with it. CTRL+backspace works for deleting chunks though.

The first of the two (may have) happened after I changed my keymap from US to GB but switching back and forth hasn't solved the problem.

Running ARCH linux, everything is up to date and no other applications are affected, I don't have sticky keys on.

Thanks for any suggestions!

EDIT: Tried a reinstall, didn't help...

Solved Edit: Yep, you're completely right I seem to have done some super-fast rebind without noticing. I also learnt that package manager will essentially never touch .config files as they're generated by the app and so aren't under the manager's jurisdiction. Solved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CoqIDE key bindings and other preferences are stored in `.coq/` or `.config/coq`. They are not deleted on uninstall and are shared if you have various versions of Coq installed at the same time (and this may be a problem).

If you are not worried about losing any specific preferences that you configured, I would advise to just delete this directory and let CoqIDE create it fresh again.

If you are worried, then just have a look at the files (quite long but also quite readable). For instance:

```
cat .config/coq/coqide.keys | grep "tab"
```

yields the following on my machine:

```
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/View/Previous tab" "<Alt>Left")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/View/Next tab" "<Alt>Right")
```

PS: your problem might have arisen because key bindings are so easy to redefine in CoqIDE that you can do it without noticing: just open a menu (example: View), hover some option (for instance: Previous tab), type something on the keyboard (for instance v) and voilà v is now a shortcut for Previous tab.

Comment: Aaah, yes that was perfect. It was exactly what I expected. I learnt that the package manager will (usually) never delete .config files as those are generated by the app itself and not the package manager. Thanks for the help!